# SQL query to get Stock Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I am working on a query to get stock details (Sale, Purchase, Returns) from sales and purchase data for a specific date range.

But this query is not returning any data when it is supposed to be.

This is the query in question:

```
select 
    pro.Name 'ItemName',
    (select (ISNULL(SUM(SPurchases.Qty),0)-ISNULL(SUM(SOrder_return.Qty),0))-(ISNULL(SUM(SSales.Qty),0)- ISNULL(SUM(SSales_returns.Qty),0)) 
from
    [Order] _SOrder
left outer join 
    Order_Item SPurchases on _SOrder.Id = SPurchases.[Order] 
                          and SPurchases.OrderType = 1 and SPurchases.Product = pro.Id
left outer join 
    Order_Item SOrder_return on _SOrder.Id = SOrder_return.[Order] 
                             and SOrder_return.OrderType = 2 and SOrder_return.Product = pro.Id
        ,Sale _SSale  
left outer join 
    Sale_Item SSales on _SSale.Id = SSales.Sale and SSales.SaleType = 1 
                     and SSales.Product = pro.Id
left outer join 
    Sale_Item SSales_returns on _SSale.Id = SSales_returns.Sale 
                             and SSales_returns.SaleType = 3 and SSales_returns.Product = pro.Id
where 
    _SOrder.Date<@StartDate
    and _SSale.Date<@StartDate) as 'Opening',   
   isnull(SUM(purchases.Qty),0) as 'Purchase',
   isnull(SUM(order_return.Qty),0) as 'PurRet',
   isnull(SUM(sales.Qty),0) as 'Sale',
   isnull(SUM(sales_returns.Qty),0) as 'SaleRet'
from 
   Product pro, [Order] _Order
left outer join 
   Order_Item purchases on _Order.Id = purchases.[Order] and purchases.OrderType = 1 
left outer join 
   Order_Item order_return on _Order.Id = order_return.[Order] and order_return.OrderType = 2 
    ,Sale _sale
left outer join 
   Sale_Item sales on _sale.Id = sales.Sale and sales.SaleType = 1 
left outer join 
   Sale_Item sales_returns on _sale.Id = sales_returns.Sale and sales_returns.SaleType = 3 
where 
   _Order.Date >= @StartDate and _Order.Date <= @EndDate
   and _sale.Date >= @StartDate and _sale.Date <= @EndDate
   and purchases.Product = pro.Id 
   and order_return.Product = pro.Id 
   and sales.Product = pro.Id 
   and sales_returns.Product = pro.Id 
group by 
   pro.Name, pro.Id
```

[I have uploaded the the complete schema with data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a620/14) to SqlFiddle should you need more information on the schema and the data.

Comment: I'm too lazy to look at your link.

Comment: @DanBracuk that link is actually quite valuable since it provides a nice view of the schema, the data and the query in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bunch of items in the where clause

```
and purchases.Product=pro.Id and order_return.Product=pro.Id and sales.Product=pro.Id and sales_returns.Product=pro.Id
```

Which can only be true if all the items in the outer join are present. Given that you chose to do an outer join I'm going to assume that they're optional and thus not always there.

Instead of putting them in the where, put them in the join statement:

```
left outer join Sale_Item sales_returns on 
                    on _sale.Id=sales_returns.Sale 
                       and sales_returns.SaleType=3 
                       and sales_returns.Product=pro.Id
```